# Show users that were modified at least 2 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
User:
ID, Name

UserChanges:
ID, UserID, ChangeDate
```

Each time the users changes his name, a new row is inserted in UserChanges.
So UserChanges my contains several rows with the same UserID.

I would like to get the list of the User.name that changed at least twice, and one of their modifications was after the 15/12/2013.

So, first select all users that are referenced more than once in the UserChanges table.
In this list, select those who changed after the 15/12/2013.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag questions with the appropriate database engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the user and then count the changes and if one of them is on or after the specified date

```
select u.name
from user u
inner join userchanges c on c.userid = u.id
group by u.name
having count(c.id) > 1
and sum(case when ChangeDate >= '2013-12-15' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```